# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I mapped two tables and created scaffolding in MVC. After filling data in the form when I click on create button, below error occurs.

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A value shared across entities or associations
>   is generated in more than one location. Check that mapping does not
>   split an EntityKey to multiple store-generated columns.

Comment: Show the tables and their mapping. Also the updating code.

Answer (score 4):

If cannot see any innerexception message that can help you (during debug), I have found the solution of the "Identity Specification" problem.

In SQL Management Studio (or in Server Explorer in Visual Studio) you have to open the table that causes your problem and select che primary key. Looking at its property you will find the "Identity Specification". You have to set it to "yes".

Source: http://www.technologycrowds.com/2015/07/system-data-entity-infrastructure-DbUpdateException.html

Answer (score 3):

This issue typically happens when you have a sub-type table mapping, but its primary key is set to auto-generate. this is problematic, since EF will be explicitly setting the value based on the key of the root entity.

if the above is the problem indeed, then to solve it, set the "**`Identity Specification`**" of your child table to false. i.e. Remove the **`StoreGeneratedPattern="identity"`** from the EDMX.

Comment: How to set the "Identity Specification" of your child table to false. I searched everywhere in .edmx file but could not find this option. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

check primary key in the table if not then **set primary key** to the id
and identity specification to "is identity to **YES**"

Answer (score 0):

In entity framework if you mentioned any field as key then it should have the Isidentity property as true,otherwise it will throw this erroe.

open SQL Management Studio  you have to open the table that causes your problem and select the primary key(As mentioned in model). Looking at its property you will find the "Identity Specification". You have to set it to "yes".